# Making responsive height CSS

Tags: html, css

I can't get the divs to cover the full image height, but when i resize it doesn't cover the full height of the image.

```
width:50%;
height:100%;
```

Width works but the height doesn't.

Comment: Could you please add the code so that I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using 100% in height you can replace it with 100vh.

```
height:100vh;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a 100% height on all your parent elements